# How to create multiple graph for multiple group in R

Tags: r, graph, boxplot

I have a large date frame that has this structure :

```
view(data.frame)
Group   Height
Green    10
Green    45
Green    23
Red      11
Red      8
Red      230
```

For information, I have 300 different groups. What I want is to do one graph (boxplot) by group. Ideally, I want them to be in the same graph, with "Group" in the x-axis and "Height" in  the y-axis. But, with 300 groups, I don't know if it's possible to have them in the same big graph.

Thank you !

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Usually, questions on SO are specific to a coding attempt. What did you try that did not work (i.e., error, undesired result)? What did you [research](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1586) before asking question? With R, there are multiple ways to solve your broad plotting question.

Comment: Stack Overflow focuses on questions and answers to *specific* **programming** questions. It seems this question focuses on an approach to data visualization, and thus is not appropriate for SO as defined in the [help/on-topic]. Some such questions may be on topic for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), but please review their [help center](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but whether it is legible or useful is another matter.

Here is one approach using `ggplot` with some made up data which may or may not  be relevant to your dataset.

To manage the visual overload the 300 groups are arbitrarily split into  three sub-groups and facetted.

A better understanding of your data and what you want to visualise would help to find a possible solution.

```r
library(ggplot2)


ggplot(df)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = height, x =factor(group), group = group))+
  facet_wrap(~g1, scales = "free_x", nrow = 3)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 6))
```

[image]

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(group = rep(1:300, each = 10),
                 height = runif(3000, 5, 250),
                 g1 = rep(c("Groups 1-100", "Groups 101-200", "Groups 201-300" ), each = 1000))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>